# How to use coroutines in a Kotlin Library

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

how do i correctly use coroutines in a Library class which has nothing to do with the activity lifecycle?

For now, i created a private property in my class:

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
```

and have a cancel method, to cancel the scope.

```
 public fun cancel() {
        coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
 }
```

Is there any cleaner way to make this work, without having to call cancel on my library class in onPause/OnStop?

EDIT:

Also, an additional question: Does it matter, if my created CoroutineContext is in a Singleton? Like this:

```
public object MyObject {
   
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
}
```

Is there any danger of memory leaks or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply said no, you create a scope when you need it, you cancel it when you don't need it anymore. Scope takes care of the lifecycle of all the coroutines
fired from it. A coroutine is an instance of suspendable computation. Once you do not need that computation anymore you cancel it, in order to save computational power where it's really needed. To avoid tracking all the fired coroutine by their jobs, we have a scope. Imagine having 1000 independent coroutines and having to track 1000 jobs to cancel them, instead of that, we have a scope to cancel them all at once. You can simply call `scope.cancel()`.

One way how you can avoid manually calling `cancel()` in `onPause/onStop` is to use observation pattern, make your library class implement `LifecycleObserver` interface and have it observe the `Lifecycle` of an  `Activity/Fragment` of interest.

A Singleton is just a single ever existing instance of a class, there's no reason why would there be any problems having `CoroutineScope` instance inside of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I think that this approach makes sense for me

Answer (score 2):

> how do i correctly use coroutines in a Library class which has nothing to do with the activity lifecycle?

Well, I would recommend you don't create `coroutineScope` inside your library `class`, instead you turn your class function into `suspend` function by specifying which thread **(Dispatcher)** it should run on:

```
suspend fun doWork() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {    //run on IO thread
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

**AND THEN,** use built-in `coroutineScope` like `viewModelScope` from `ViewModel`, or `lifecycleScope` from `Activity / Fragment` to execute this `suspend` function. Those built-in `coroutineScopes` will be auto-canceld after the `ViewModel` or `Activity / Fragment` get destroyed, so you don't need to worry about them:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    myLibrayObject.doWork()    //<- suspend function, you decide the thread inside this function
}
```

- How to choose thread **(Dispatcher)**:
  https://youtu.be/ZTDXo0-SKuU?t=392
  https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv#main-safety

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was already thinking about this option, but as I need to keep compatibility with Java projects, I think I am not able to go with this approach, as this would have publicly exposed suspend functions